# CMS caching advice

Tags: asp.net, caching, content-management-system, nosql

I'm developping a video cms using .Net. There two main object types:
Category: hierarchy structure.
Item: Base cms object which can have custom attributes.
Each item belongs to one or many categories.
This system will provide service for many different companies so each item and category has a company relation.
System will use EntityFramework to retrieve data from MsSql Database.
System will give single item or ordered item list based on a order filter.

I need an advice to retrieve data from source and provide results in a short time.
I searched distributed cache solutions like app fabric and some nosql solutions but im not sure how to build my system.

Should i cache all items and produce results based on the cached items or should i cache results and then serve them? What and how should i use?

Answer (score 0):

When you need your content to be delivered with lowest latency, it would be better to go for a  distributed cache like Windows App Fabric, where you can distribute the cache across different nodes.

I would recommend that you can cache categories with the idea that the categories will not be updated often and also you can have company based cache for the company items. since the custom properties are involved, you should be very careful not to have stale or invalid data in the cache and that is upto your application logic.

Comment: That is what I thought but I'm struggling with how to cache or store items. I mean client can request variant of item list with sorting options. When I cache these results i would cache same items with different order. I want to use also ram efficiently but is it an impossible thing?

Comment: @genesistr: I would like to suggest you to have a cache of items list accross all companies and then have the sorting order cache for companies so when a customer requests items, you can get the items from the cache and then apply the sorting order [again from cache]. Hope this works fine for your usecase

Comment: thanks for the advice. I thought about this solution but i wasnt sure about it. I will go with this solution. Hope it works fine. (+1 for your help)

Comment: @genesistr: Thank you, do share your implementation feedback or any queries. :)